# how to use generics in react function components with RefForwardingComponent?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks

when i use forwardRef in react, and my code is as below:

```
interface FProps<P, T> {
    name: P
    birth: T
}

interface Handler {}

const Comp: RefForwardingComponent<Handler, FProps<P, T>> = <P, T>(
    { name, birth }: FProps<P, T>,
    ref
) => {

    useImperativeHandle(ref, () => ({
        name
  }))
  
    return <div>{name}</div>
}

export default forwardRef(Comp)
```

but i got:

[image]

how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The generic `P` depends on the arguments of the function and only becomes known when the function is called, so you can't use it define the function itself.  Instead we have to define the arguments:

```
const Comp = <P, T>(
    { name, birth }: FProps<P, T>,
    ref: ((instance: Handler | null) => void) | MutableRefObject<Handler | null> | null,
) => {
...
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDGMA0cDeAzaAdxSgBNk9sBXAZyQElwkoUZgA3JACRQDtSANkmwBZKjBQAjIRQDykgFZIMAXzh4oEEHABEUVBh0BuALAAoc8F4xmedEjgAxAAqawNADzPsAFQB8uOZwwXC8KCBIAFxwzkEhksCwABbRPuYq5pbWtvZwPPxCULgZFmZoELw08ADCWmBwALxwXr5%20ABRxwTih4cJwCclwKtEubp7ecP6YnXD6eNFtbVZVfGhReXyCzHAAPqFUAgIAlI0B7BDApCd7YhLSSHKKyjAe%20VtFe7wHAgGf39NmE4NAI4TJmEJwWgMJgsNicN5CNpzbBtIEBNqg8EQkJhCJxFRHI5xGb6GBUKC8ZqkDh%20HC4pAqDwAemp7D86TBSAAHpBYHBSEg7Ad4AQoMQyBQ2rVwEcgA)

Comment: thanks a lot for your answer, i know the reason why it not works, would you mind helping me with another question. this is the link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64552303/how-to-export-generic-types-with-react-forwardref